# How to display nested array data of json into html page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

students.json

```
{   
"students": [
 {
    "studentname": "Rohit Kumar",
    "grade": "A",
    "student": [
       {
            "SNo": "1",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Numbers"
       },
       {
            "SNo": "2",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Number System"
       }
   ]
}
]
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iTop Bird Eye View</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $.getJSON("students.json").then(function(data)
            {console.log(data);
               var tr = data
                for (var i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++) {
                var tr = $('<tr/>');
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].SNo + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].Subject + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].Concept + "</td>");
                $('.table1').append(tr);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="90%">
            <tr valign="top" align="center">
                <td>
                    <table width="95%" id="s_name">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Student Name: {{  }}</td>
                            <td align="right">Grade: {{  }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <table class="data-table table1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SNo.</th>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                                <th>Concept</th>                            
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in json and In this code I have nested array in my students.json file and I want to display json file data into index.html file but probably right now it display nothing to me. I don't know where I am doing wrong. So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thnak You

Comment: Your json seems to be incorrect

Comment: How is `students.json` created?  Is it a file that you've created or is it a response from a web service?

Comment: Take a look @Archer is .json ok or not

Comment: It's mostly okay now (depends on the browser - some don't like a comma at the end of a list of objects, so remove them from `"Numbers",` and `"Number System",`

Comment: okay got it I think now its fine @Archer

Comment: The `students` array has an array of objects that at first glance look like student information, but then they also have an array called `student`.  So, to get the name (for example) you would use `data.students[0].studentname` but then you also have an array that looks to me like subjects and you would get that from `data.students[0].student[i]` where `i` is the index.

Comment: still same nothing happen @Archer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the basis of what you need, but I'd recommend making some changes as well as fixing the issues.

Your JSON has an array of students, with a name and a grade, and then that also has an array so you'd need to loop through the students and also loop through each sub-array to get the rest of the information.  The code below shows that.

I've made it work on this page, in the snippet, so you can see it in action.

I've modified it to build the table as a string of HTML and then add that to the page in one hit.  It's much better than using `.append()` over and over again.  I've also made this build the table and contained tables from scratch, so you'll have to modify the generated HTML if you want to change the structure or add any extra attributes (css classnames, for example).

```js
var data = {
    "students": [{
        "studentname": "Rohit Kumar",
        "grade": "A",
        "student": [{
            "SNo": "1",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Numbers"
        }, {
            "SNo": "2",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Number System"
        }]
    }, {
        "studentname": "Archer",
        "grade": "A++",
        "student": [{
            "SNo": "1",
            "Subject": "Stack Overflow",
            "Concept": "Ruling"
        }, {
            "SNo": "2",
            "Subject": "Stack Overflow",
            "Concept": "Being a boss"
        }, {
            "SNo": "3",
            "Subject": "Stack Overflow",
            "Concept": "Answering your question"
        }]
    }]
};

var html = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='90%'>";

for (var i = 0, il = data.students.length; i < il; i++) {

    html += "<tr valign='top' align='center'>";
    html += "<td>";

    // add the student information
    html += "<table width='95%'>";
    html += "<tr valign='top' align='center'>";
    html += "<td>Student Name: " + data.students[i].studentname + "</td>";
    html += "<td>Grade: " + data.students[i].grade + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
    html += "</table>";

    html += "<table class='data-table table1'>";
    html += "<thead>";
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<th>SNo.</th>";
    html += "<th>Subject</th>";
    html += "<th>Concept</th>";
    html += "</tr>";
    html += "</thead>";
    html += "<tbody>";

    // add the subject information
    for (var j = 0, jl = data.students[i].student.length; j < jl; j++) {
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].SNo + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Subject + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Concept + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    }

    html += "</tbody>";
    html += "</table>";
    html += "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";

document.getElementById("student-table-container").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="student-table-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iTop Bird Eye View</title>



    </head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="90%">
            <tr valign="top" align="center">
                <td>
                    <table width="95%" id="s_name">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Student Name: {{  }}</td>
                            <td align="right">Grade: {{  }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <table class="data-table table1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SNo.</th>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                                <th>Concept</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
    var data = {
"students": [
 {
    "studentname": "Rohit Kumar",
    "grade": "A",
    "student": [
       {
            "SNo": "1",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Numbers"
       },
       {
            "SNo": "2",
            "Subject": "Maths",
            "Concept": "Number System"
       }
   ]
}
]
};
          var tr = data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++) {

              var els = $('#s_name td');

              els[0].innerText = "Student Name: " + data.students[i].studentname;

              els[1].innerText = "Grade: " + data.students[i].grade;

              for(var j = 0;j < data.students[i].student.length;j++) {
                var tr = $('<tr/>');

                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].SNo + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Subject + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Concept + "</td>");
                $('.table1').append(tr);
              }

            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on your above provided json you would need to do the following but I still think there is something not right with the json. Please double check to be sure. I will edit my answer accordingly

```
var tr = data
        for (var i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++) {

          var els = $('#s_name td');

          els[0].innerText = "Student Name: " + data.students[i].studentname;

          els[1].innerText = "Grade: " + data.students[i].grade;

          for(var j = 0;j < data.students[i].student.length;j++) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');

            $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].SNo + "</td>");
            $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Subject + "</td>");
            $(tr).append("<td>" + data.students[i].student[j].Concept + "</td>");
            $('.table1').append(tr);
          }

        }
```

Comment: I am doing this but now its not working still same @cdoshi

Comment: I am also want to display studentname and grade as well @cdoshi

Comment: Ok I see, but now based on that your html and JS would also change. How exactly do you want it

Comment: I want studentname, grade in my html page I have use {} braces where I want name and grade and also want to display sno. subject, concept into table body